# Word for 'an event automatically happening earlier than planned, caused by something else'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

**How would you call an action (or event) that occurs earlier than originally planned, in reaction to some condition or other event happening?**

Examples:

- When you put a pan on a stove with a timer, but turn the heat off before the timer rings, because the water boiled earlier.
- When a ticket website has tickets available till next Sunday, but sales close automatically on Friday due to all tickets being sold out.
- When you buy Bitcoin at 400 USD exchange rate, and have it automatically sold it when it dropped to 350 USD.

Sample of use:

- *I would have watched the whole episode but my access was ceased due to THAT_WORD_NOUN and I couldn't anymore.*
- *She tried to bid that item higher, but someone THAT_WORD_VERB'ed the auction and it was over.*

The words that I found that I think you could sometimes use in such cases are `'short circuit'` or `'trip wire'`, although these are usually used with particular context, not broadly (eg. you don't *'trip wire an auction'*). Thesaurus doesn't help with either of these.

I'm wondering if there is another word that more precisely describes such action / event. The word doesn't have a negative or positive connotation. Bonus points if it's a single word, not compound word / phrase.

Comment: It was triggered prematurely.

Comment: It was ***cut short***.  The sale was cut short. The auction was cut short. The time was cut short.  Some of your examples are fundamentally different though and cannot be covered by a single verb.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, both also correct in some cases. I went with Preempt as suggested by stevesilva seeing it's a single word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the bullet points lead here:

> [***forestall***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/forestall) - to prevent something from happening by acting first

But the noun/verb usage cases might be better fits for **preemption**/*preempted*:

> [***preempt***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preempt) - to prevent from happening or taking place

Comment: Just to clarify - Forestall is only a verb, Preempt is both a verb and a noun. Went with Preempt. Thank you!

Comment: @voy *Preempt* is not a noun at all; I don't know where you got that idea.

Comment: I've found a number of sources that claim so Jason. Please support your contradiction with some facts and sources, so that we could learn if it really isn't a noun